# Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a complex app and it gives me the following warning:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

In two words this warning occurs when I press an 'add' button, that should add another component to my app. Here is a corresponding piece of code:

```
<Button onClick={addChartHandler.bind(this)}><Glyphicon glyph="plus" /></Button>
```

`addChartHandler` comes from it's container component:

```
addChartHandler() {
    store.dispatch(addChart());
}
```

addChart simply increases the components counter. And the app container subscribes to these changes:

```
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
    return {
        count: store.app.chartsCount
    };
}
```

It's hard for me to trace the warning, but I called `console.log` each time every component renders. It appears that this warning pops out after rendering this component (which is dumb component for my `App`):

```
render() {
    let charts = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.count; i++) {
        charts.push(<ChartContainer id={i} key={i} size={this.props.size} />);
    }
    console.log('APP RENDER');
    console.log(charts);
    return (
        <div className="container-padding">
            <NavContainer />
            {charts}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Been working on that for at least three hours, ran out of ideas.

Comment: What is the ChartContainer doing?

Comment: @Christian obtains the data needed to draw a chart (using chart.js)

Answer (score 2):

This is the line of code because of code which causes the issue I feel:-

```
  for (let i = 0; i < this.props.count; i++) {
        charts.push(<ChartContainer id={i} key={i} size={this.props.size} />);
    }
```

I think you are doing `setState` somewhere in render or your state is updating where it should not do. Can you share you `ChartContainer` component once?

Can you try this out?

```
constructor(){
   state : {
     charts : []
  } 
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.count != this.props.count){
     let charts = []
     for (let i = 0; i < this.props.count; i++) {
        charts.push(<ChartContainer id={i} key={i} size={this.props.size}      />);
    }
   this.setState({charts:charts})
  }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-padding">
            <NavContainer />
            {this.state.charts}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers, I solved the issue: I was invoking `setState` in some other component's `constructor()`. For those either looking: double-check all of your other components, and their `render()` and `constructor()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helps me to clear my thoughts.

I was facing that error because I added `this.setState({});` in constructor it self.

So I moved it to `componentWillReceiveProps` and It worked!

Thank you @Harkirat Saluja